# hashing password in meanjs

Tags: angularjs, hash, passwords, meanjs

I'm reading source code of meanjs and my question is the hashPassword method with the code:

```
UserSchema.methods.hashPassword = function(password) {
   if (this.salt && password) {
        return crypto.pbkdf2Sync(password, this.salt, 10000, 64).toString('base64');
    } else {
        return password;
    }
};
```

Here I can't understand why it is returning password, in case this.salt && password is false? As I understand, that is a problem and perhaps it should stop saving the user, right?

Comment: That sure looks like a buggy implementation to me. I would expect it to trigger an error if the salt were initialized incorrectly. As it is written, the best you can do is an `===` check on the before and after hash. It also really bothers me that a server side module for password protection would be so terse.

Comment: See my answer below.  With just this single block of code as context, the implementation does seem buggy but in the big picture of things, it isn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had some issues with this method and change it to this

```
if (this.password && this.password.length > 6) {
    if (!this.salt || this.salt.length === 0) {
        this.salt = crypto.randomBytes(16).toString('base64');
        this.password = this.hashPassword(this.password);
    }
}
```

The bug is that if you ever try to save user again after initial save you will not be able to login with that user details.
What would happen it would use salt to encrypt already encrypted password which is in my opinion is wrong.

So two options to handle that issue one is that you always set user password to empty string before you call save or you do what I did or something along those lines.

Answer (score 2):

Directly before the hashPassword function defintion, you should see this block:

```
    /**
     * Hook a pre save method to hash the password
     */
    UserSchema.pre('save', function(next) {
      if (this.password && this.password.length > 6) {
        this.salt = new Buffer(crypto.randomBytes(16).toString('base64'), 'base64');
        this.password = this.hashPassword(this.password);
      }

      next();
    });
```

As you can see, a salt is generated right before hashPassword is called.  If you are using meanjs properly, the plain password will never be returned.  If salt is undefined for any reason, instead of throwing an error it continues and saves the password in plain text.